# Update has broken my ActiveX controls

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am having an issue with the following code block.  Works fine in Excel 2010 but will not work in Excel 2013.

Is there an issue with OLE Control Objects in 2013 VBA or am I missing something?

The code stops at "ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value = Format(Range("JanBud").Value, "$###,###")" and returns an error of:

> Run-Time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub firstQtrByMonth()

'MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name


ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value = Format(Range("JanBud").Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthOneLabel.Value = "Jan"
ActiveSheet.monthTwoBudTxt.Value = Format(Range("FebBud").Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthTwoLabel.Value = "Feb"
ActiveSheet.monthThreeBudTxt.Value = Format(Range("MarBud").Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthThreeLabel.Value = "Mar"

ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value = Format(Range("JanAct").Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthTwoActTxt.Value = Format(Range("FebAct").Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthThreeActTxt.Value = Format(Range("MarAct").Value, "$###,###")


ActiveSheet.monthOneIncDecTxt.Value = Format((ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value / ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value), "#%")
ActiveSheet.monthTwoIncDecTxt.Value = Format((ActiveSheet.monthTwoActTxt.Value / ActiveSheet.monthTwoBudTxt.Value), "#%")
ActiveSheet.monthThreeIncDecTxt.Value = Format((ActiveSheet.monthThreeActTxt.Value / ActiveSheet.monthThreeBudTxt.Value), "#%")

'ActiveSheet.monthlyBreakDownHeader.Value = "1st Qtr Monthly Breakdown"

'ActiveSheet.quarterlyBreakdownHeader.Value = "1st Qtr Analysis"

ActiveSheet.QtrBudTotal.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value + ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value + _
ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value, "$###,###")

ActiveSheet.QtrActTotal.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value + ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value + _
ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value, "$###,###")

ActiveSheet.monthOneVariance.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.monthOneActTxt.Value - ActiveSheet.monthOneBudTxt.Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthTwoVariance.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.monthTwoActTxt.Value - ActiveSheet.monthTwoBudTxt.Value, "$###,###")
ActiveSheet.monthThreeVariance.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.monthThreeActTxt.Value - ActiveSheet.monthThreeBudTxt.Value, "$###,###")


'ActiveSheet.cisCompBreakDownHeader.Value = "First Quarter CIS Comparison"


End Sub
```

Comment: Found the answer on another forum:

http://excelmatters.com/2014/12/10/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/

Answer (score 1):

Seems was yet another manifestation of the defective update at the start of the month.